# AngularJS routing, pass id with ui-sref while displaying a slug and not the id in the url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, angular-routing

I'll outline what I've set up and what I'd like to work:

I have a list of items in my template like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users">
        <a ui-sref="user({slug: user.slug, id: user.id})">
            {{user.name}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have a state provider looking like this:

```
.state('user', {
    url: '/:slug',
    controller: 'UserCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'app/user/userProfile.html',
    resolve: {
         user: function($stateParams, UserService) {
             return UserService.get($stateParams.id);
         }
    }
});
```

Now I understand that this isn't working because the `id` parameter is not defined in the `url` and so it isn't passed to the `$stateParams`. I have seen similar questions answered with suggestions of using something like this:

```
resolve: {
     user: function($stateParams, UserService) {
         var userId = UserService.getIdFromSlug($stateParams.slug);
         return UserService.get(userId);
     }
}
```

But the `getIdFromSlug` method is either going to require another API call or when I get the list, creating a mapping object in the service like `{ slug: id }`. Both don't seem like very elegant solutions, especially since I already have the `id`.

Am I missing something? Is there no other way to pass parameters through to the state provider? (I am fairly new to Angular).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.state('user', {
    url: '/:slug',
 params: { id: { value: -1 } },
```

I have used the above so the ids where not passed in the url.

Comment: This seems to work a treat thanks. I've tried to find similar examples in the docs but I'm struggling. Where did you get this solution from? Any links/refs you could point me to?

Comment: @lopsided This is where I found it. [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#params) 

"A map which optionally configures parameters declared in the url, or defines additional non-url parameters."

Comment: I read this bit: "Only use this within a state if you are not using url" and so read straight past it. Works perfectly, also allows you to pass full objects through. Not sure why the docs say only to use this if not using url...

Comment: The value of `id` won't be retained upon page refresh on user state though.

Comment: Check out UI Router URL Matcher.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass both slug and id , but than you have to code both in the url

```
url: '/:slug/:id'
```

like this you can pass both

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having the id in the url. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `id` in the url like

```
url: '/:slug/:id'
```

Or treat it as the query string like below

```
url: '/:slug&id
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having the id in the url. Thanks though.